# redirect from localhost to localhost/abc/

Tags: php, redirect

I have placed an `index.php` file in the root of my web site (`http://localhost`).

I want to redirect this page (`http://localhost`) to `http:/localhost/abc` - when I visit `http://localhost`, I want the user to go to `http://localhost/abc`.

What do I need to do to my `index.php` file?

Comment: A google search for "php redirect" would have been easier than writing this article

Comment: You could say that for 90% of the posts on here.

Comment: Even a StackOverflow search for "php redirect" would have been easier.

Comment: It was probably in the dropdown for titles. Meh, the question will soon be marked answered and we can all move on.

Comment: Need I remind y'all that the authors of S.O. want an answer on S.O. to come up when someone googles the question?

Answer (score 8):

What about something like this in your first `index.php` :

```
header('Location: http://localhost/abc');
exit;
```

*(BTW, you forgot some slashes after '`http:`' in your OP ^^ )*

Anything/anyone that comes to this first page will be redirected to the 'abc' one.

See [`header`](http://www.php.net/header), for more informations.

One thing : make sure nothing is send to the ouput before calling the `header` function, else you might get an error : headers cannot be sent if any output *(like HTML code, or even white spaces !)* has already been generated.

Comment: I've fixed the slashes, etc. for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an HTTP Redirect using the `header` command in PHP.

So, in order to redirect someone, you must put this command before any whitespace in your program (spaces or HTML outside of the PHP tags):

```
<?php 
    header("Location: http://localhost/abc");
?>
```

This will send a Redirect Header to the browser, which will then redirect the user.

Because it is up to the 'browser' to redirect the user, you want to make sure no more PHP is outputted onto the screen, so use either `exit` or `die` to make sure no more code is ran

```
<?php 
    header("Location: http://localhost/abc");
    exit();
?>
```

or,

```
<?php 
    header("Location: http://localhost/abc");
    die("Your browser does not support redirection. Please go to http://localhost/abc.");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome .
This Redirecting Is An Important Thing That You have To Learn .

You Can Use This Code

```
    <?php
  header( 'Location: http://localhost/...' );
  exit();
?>
```

You Can Find Tutorial About PHP [w3 schools](http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp)