# php header function prepending the current directory

Tags: php

I am new to php and I faced this problem while redirecting to other php files. To make my question clear I created two php files. first.php and second.php.Both this files are found in /var/www/test/.
This is the code in first.php

```
<?php
$url = "localhost/test/second.php";
header("Location:$url");   ?>
```

This is the code in second.php

```
<?php
echo("this is the second page"); ?>
```

And when I browse to first.php file I got this in my Firefox browser.

**The requested URL /test/localhost/test/second.php was not found on this server.**

**test/** is added to the header string, which is clear as you can see. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072042/headerlocation-redirect-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-remote-server or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284338/redirect-from-localhost-to-localhost-abc

Answer (score 0):

The server is appending your parameter to the current working directory. To make it clear to your server, that this is an entirely new URI, prepend your parameter with `http://`. That way it becomes an absolute URI:

```
$url = "http://localhost/test/second.php";
```

If you have problems with `localhost` not being resolved properly, refer to the questions linked by @gen.